# passing stream objects from java to c++

Tags: android, android-ndk, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am developing an android application that can connect to a Bluetooth SPP device. The data of the BT device should be processed by an native executable. The executable (normally running under Linux) also sends start and stop commands to the BT device.

After connecting to the BT device (in java) I have an input and output stream similar to the android Bluetooth chat example.

So, is it possible to get a reference of the streams from which my native application can read and write to?

I have also tried to directly read from /dev/smd2 with boost asio after the connection was established. Unfortunately I have gotten an end of file exception.
Thanks

Comment: In order to run a native Linux executable on Android, you need a rooted device. Also, the owner ID of the java code is the Dalvik machine which is different from the executable so you probably couldn't share handles. Is it possible to just call native code methods with the data read/written from the Java side?